# Facebook Page Plugin width doesn't apply

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to implement the [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin). I set the width to 500, but it always stays at 280px.

```
<div id="facebook-feed" style="text-align: center">
            <div class="fb-page zdepth-1" data-width="400" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow

```
.fb_iframe_widget {width:500px !important;}
```

only works sometimes for me. But I finally figured out what really caused the problem. I had the plugin wrapped in a div with display set to none. I changed it to inline-block and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Case of poor documentation:

the parent element can override the plugin width in only one direction - by squeezing it. Set the `data-width="500"` (max) and make your wrapper element smaller ex: `width: 280px;`

Answer (score 1):

The **Page Plugin** tries to fit in smaller containers/screens

- The plugin renders at a smaller width (to fit in smaller screens) automatically, if the container is of slimmer than the configured width.
- It tries to render nicely on smaller screens assuming the container squeezes for mobile.

So probably, in your case the container holding the plugin is smaller than configured width i.e. `500px`.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is hard to test this without the rest of your code, you should be able to adjust the width of the div class by adding `width="500px"` directly into your HTML.

This method has worked for me espically with different embeds, including the facebook plugin.

If you choose to add it using CSS, try adding:

```
.fb-page zdepth-1 {width:500px;}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I think because the plugin generates an iframe and I can't directly modify it. Or can I? But I tried .fb_iframe_widget {width:500px !important;} and it works.  Should've tried that earlier. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
.fb-page zdepth-1 {width:500px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this style to my `iframe` element fixed my code:

```css
style="width:100%"
```